# Dispatching functions with different signatures

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```
/* @flow */

type BaseProps = {
  commonProp1: number,
  commonProp2: string,
}

type Type1Props = BaseProps & {
  type: 'type1',
  extraProp1: boolean,
}

type Type2Props = BaseProps & {
  type: 'type2',
  extraProp2: number,
}

type Type = Type1Props | Type2Props;

function dealWithType1({ props }: {props: Type1Props}) {
  console.log('common prop 1', props.commonProp1);
  console.log('type1 extra prop', props.extraProp1);
}
function dealWithType2({ props }: {props: Type2Props}) {
  console.log('common prop 1', props.commonProp1);
  console.log('type2 extra prop', props.extraProp2);
}

function branch({ props }: { props: Type }) {
  const a = {
    type1: dealWithType1,
    type2: dealWithType2,
  }[props.type];
  return a({props});
}
```

The [above code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBCAhgM54AKATnDqWALxgDeqYYAxnALbdwB21WgEYAXGH4BXbgCM8VADRtOPPoJo4ATONIYqAS34BzJQF902fGAAquPMKF1GRMpQ30AZC2WW84gOS+wv5K7HgAHnrEjmJgMnBwMHjE-GYWdjZ2mo70TCTkOWBerOy+Ab6aIcoRUY7aEtJyiqjmmBm2Vkwd9oUAPpn42e4A3OhQkvwcGPoCYAAmyTAA6voYABbdwgAUzGA47mCm4sz7tKTimzmmAJTe7Fz8pIl4AHTwRlv+XLyzpzhgwQUe3cL2+ahi11G9wETySbzgH0CdmEYBqVGIwNoIUxdBeaOiGmEkJaqHGk2mswWxGWqw2WR2OPoRxYf3OAzwQzONzuKkez3hiLBvw0AOxrNBqgEEKhvNhr3enwqqMi6JxYpB+LqxNaZKmM34cXRkzWDNZh2OjIuGW5JVlGDAGKYttKyPEVJp602oXYYAqbsWK09WW9pgA2uLfABdGVUPAYSRUA3EHasm6jUxAA) shows a function (`branch`) that dispatches either of two other functions depending on the property `type`.  All functions accept an object with a common number of properties declared in `BaseProps` while each of the individual dispatched functions handles a number of extra properties which depend on the `type`.  Those extended objects are declared as the intersection of `BaseProps` plus the extras.  The generic type is declared as a disjoint union of all the possible object types.

This is a simplified version of my issue, though it produces the same errors.  In the actual case, all are React stateless components so, basically, functions, except they have their initials in uppercase and are called as JSX components: `<A props={props} />`. I am showing the above simplified version which still reports the same errors I get with the actual JSX version.

My guess is that I should explicitly declare `a` and its arguments and I have tried to do so in several ways without success. The actual code works fine, just as it did before I started trying out Flow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found the solution and now that I see it, it makes sense.  I have to declare `type` in the generic type `BaseProps` as a generic `string`:

```
type BaseProps = {
  type: string, // <-- this was missing
  commonProp1: number,
  commonProp2: string,
}
```

Declaring it as as a string is not incompatible with the more specific type definitions where only certain string values are allowed for it.